# Which flag to set in Visual Studio/Makefile to ensure "extra qualification on member" triggers a compile error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

Is there any flag/option to set in Visual Studio (2013) to ensure "extra qualification on member" is detected as an error ?

Is there any flag/option to set in a makefile to ensure "extra qualification on member" is detected as an error?

For each of these will it also detect other errors ?

If yes, is it possible to detect only that error, using some sort of filter ?